# How are minions chosen for given pod creation request

Tags: kubernetes

How does kubernetes choose the minion among many available for a given pod creation command? Is it something that can be controlled/tweaked ?

If replicated pods are submitted for deployment, is kubernetes intelligent enough to place them in different minions if they expose the same container/host port pair? Or does it always place different replicas in different minions ?

What about corner cases like what if two different pods (not necessarily replicas) that expose same host/container port pair are submitted? Will they carefully be placed on different minions ?

If a pod requires specific compute/memory requirements, can it be placed in a minion/host that has sufficient resources left to meet those requirement?

In summary, is there detailed documentation on kubernetes pod placement strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pods are scheduled to ports using the algorithm in [generic_scheduler.go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/scheduler/generic_scheduler.go)

There are rules that prevent host-port conflicts, and also to make sure that there are sufficient memory and cpu requirements. [predicates.go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/scheduler/predicates.go)

Answer (score 1):

One way to choose minion for pod creation is using nodeSelector. Inside the yaml file of pod specify the label of minion for which you want to choose the minion.

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Pod
 metadata:
  name: nginx1 
  labels:
   env: test
 spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx 
    image: nginx 
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector: 
   key: value
```